# Android check socket status before connecting

Tags: android, serversocket

I am creating one SerevrSocket with some port number.
But sometimes I get `BindException` saying `Address already in use`.

So is there any mechanism by which I can check before binding ServerSocket whether it is in use or not.

And also what is the best way of handling `BindException`?

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you aren't closing your socket correctly before your program exits. 
The socket needs to be closed in onDestroy method.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
                    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(0);
                     port = server.getLocalPort();


                     server.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e1){
                    Log.e("Error in Finding socket",e1.getMessage());
                }
```

above code snippet gives you the free port available. But as mentioned earlier, check the socket closure for previous connections.